# How can I populate a value in a select statement using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2008

Precursor: **I have to use the stored procedure** and I'm using SQL Server 2000. I also need to spit out a table so that Reporting Services can use it properly. I can create any database object to help get the data however.

So, Here's an example of my select statement (I'm hoping I made this look the same as what I'm actually using)

```
SELECT     
    Store.Store_ID, 
    Store.Store_Description, 
    Salaries.Income, 
    Salaries.Tax_Rate, 
    Managers.Manager_Name, 
    Employees.Employee_ID

FROM         
    Store INNER JOIN
    Managers ON Managers.Store_ID = Store.Store_ID INNER JOIN
    Employees ON Managers.Manager_ID = Employees.Manager_ID INNER JOIN
    Salaries ON Employees.Salary_Type_ID = Salaries.Salary_Type_ID 
WHERE (Store.Store_ID = 20561) 
ORDER BY Employee_ID
```

**EDIT :Since the procedure returns a single value, all I I want to do is this:**

```
SELECT     
    Store.Store_ID, 
    Store.Store_Description, 
    Salaries.Income, 
    Salaries.Tax_Rate, 
    Managers.Manager_Name, 
    Employees.Employee_ID,
    Exec proc_Get_Emplyee_estimation_Costs Employee_ID    
FROM         
    Store INNER JOIN
    Managers ON Managers.Store_ID = Store.Store_ID INNER JOIN
    Employees ON Managers.Manager_ID = Employees.Manager_ID INNER JOIN
    Salaries ON Employees.Salary_Type_ID = Salaries.Salary_Type_ID 
WHERE (Store.Store_ID = 20561) 
ORDER BY Employee_ID
```

I know I can't do that obviously, but I need to be able to use the procedure on each line using the employee number. I'm not sure how to go about this.

<strike>Can I create a function where I can use the results of the select statement in the procedure, and then tack it on to the table and return the table to Reporting Services?</strike>

Comment: What does the procedure return?

Comment: Ah right, I knew I'd forget something. It returns a single value. I'll add that to the question,

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a [User-Defind Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx%20instead) instead of a stored procedure. You can use UDFs in select statement to calculate and return the desired value as given below:

```
SELECT     
    Store.Store_ID, 
    Store.Store_Description, 
    Salaries.Income, 
    Salaries.Tax_Rate, 
    Managers.Manager_Name, 
    Employees.Employee_ID,
    udf_Get_Emplyee_estimation_Costs(Employee_ID) AS EstimationCost
FROM         
    Store INNER JOIN
    Managers ON Managers.Store_ID = Store.Store_ID INNER JOIN
    Employees ON Managers.Manager_ID = Employees.Manager_ID INNER JOIN
    Salaries ON Employees.Salary_Type_ID = Salaries.Salary_Type_ID 
WHERE (Store.Store_ID = 20561) 
ORDER BY Employee_ID
```

User defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_Get_Emplyee_estimation_Costs
(
    Employee_ID INT
)
RETURNS DOUBLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT EstimationVal FROM SomeTable
)
```

Comment: I have to use the Stored procedure. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Christian - use a sproc but you have to call a udf in the sproc, you cant do what you want to do with a sproc calling another sproc.

Comment: hmm, so you're saying, call a function in the procedure instead of function calling the procedure? (which I can't do)

That actually makes sense, create a UDF version of the sproc, then change the sproc to just call the function. That *should* work I think.

Comment: The other option can be populating the values of stored procedure into a temp table and use the temp table in the select statement.

Comment: Well, you should put it as an answer, it worked! too bad someone voted the question down though. I feel as though it's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a function  to return a value
you can use the return value in the select statement

try
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: So I just looked into it, it doesn't look like I can call a stored procedure from inside a function